# How to get Roslyn version used by Visual Studio Code Analysis

Tags: visual-studio-2015, roslyn

When using Visual Studio 2015, Roslyn Compiler platform is used for Code Analysis.

How do I check which version of Roslyn is being used there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run code analysis on your project, a build is executed first. You can set the output verbosity in Visual Studio to "Detailed" in VS/Tools/Options/Projects and Solutions/Build and Run/MSBuild project build output verbosity.

In the output log, you'll find the following:

```
1>Using "Csc" task from assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.CodeAnalysis.dll".
1>Task "Csc"
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\csc.exe /noconfig ...
1>  Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 1.0.0.50618
1>  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
1>Done executing task "Csc".
```

And then there is the "CodeAnalysis" task which is running FxCop. FxCop analyze the output assembly, so there's no compilation involved there.

```
1>Task "CodeAnalysis"
1>  Running Code Analysis...
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop\FxCopCmd.exe  ...
```

So, the same csc.exe is used for the code analysis as for a normal build.

Comment: is this the same library that is used for static analysis?
Main reason I ask is I often get random crashes of visual studio on opening a file or project loading that point to some code analysis assemblies. 
Those crashes happen even before I actually build the solution.

Comment: _Technically_ the compiler version used at the command line and the IDE can be different. But if you're getting random crashes, don't worry about figuring out which version you're running. Instead [file a bug](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn) and send us a crash dump. We can easily figure out what is installed on your machine from the crash dump.

Answer (score 5):

You can always just do `csc /?`, and we'll print the version header.

```
>csc /?
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 1.0.0.50618
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

Comment: I have numerous csc.exe files in my filesystem. How do I know which one is being used. Especially for Code Analysis.
I will rephrase my question to be more specific.